# How to program STM32_F4VE with ST-LINK/V2/01-0

Tags: stm32, embedded, st-link

I am using keil uvision 5. I have[STM32_F4VE](https://stm32-base.org/boards/STM32F407VET6-STM32-F4VE-V2.0.html) development board and [ST-LINK/V2/01-0](https://www.evelta.com/st-link-v2-st-link-programmer-for-stm8-and-stm32/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImfCy98275AIVioBwCh3RrwaCEAYYASABEgJc2PD_BwE).
How to program this board with ST-Link v2? If you can suggest some website link also it would be helpful.

Comment: What is your specific difficulty?  What did you try?

Comment: Hi @Chris Stratton,

I got it working. Before I tried to connect

SWCLK - SWCLK,
GND - GND,
SWDIO  -   SWDIO,
VCC      -   3.3V,
with 4 wires Only. And I also tried to connect it through only FRC cable but that time none of the LED get ON.
So I tried it to connect with FRC cable from ST-LINK V2 to STM32F4xx and one USB Power cable to USB port given on the STM32F4xx board. 
-- Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
* Install STM32 STLink Utility.
* Install STSW-LINK009 driver.
* Connect ST-link V2 to the board.
* Give Power supply to the board. 
* Click load in Keil software it will ask to update the firmware of ST-link. 
  Update and dump the code to board.